# Load data from multiple filetypes into same snowflake table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Can I use multiple file-formats with different filetype to load data into same snowflake table, I read this [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-prepare.html#supported-file-formats), but it does not specify explicitly.

1. There are some files that I load from the external stage (s3) to snowflake that are in CSV format, but there is another data source for this table with a parquet file format.
2. The other requirement is to unload the whole data (CSV. + parquet) into an external stage (s3) that will follow single filetype (parquet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You can specify as many [file formats](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html) and [copy into](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html) statements for a table as you need. If you want, you can even separate the CSV and parquet files into different [stages](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html) to help keep things neatly separated.

Comment: thanks Greg for the response, can you please answer the second part of the question, can I export to s3 bucket with a uniform filetype (parquet)

Comment: Yes, you can. Snowflake supports exporting COPY INTO <location> as JSON, parquet, or CSV.

Answer (score 0):

is it not possible to use multiple file format in one copy command only.

I am having gzip, bz2, deflate formatted files in one s3 stage, so while loading these al file formats , how to use multiple file format in copy command or do we have option to specify multiple compression type while creating file format.